# How do I program for Linux's new `fanotify` file system monitoring feature?

Tags: linux, inotify, fanotify

`fanotify`, built on top of `fsnotify`, is supposed to replace `inotify` which replaced `dnotify`. Are there some good programming examples or existing utilities that use `fanotify` to watch for changes in a filesystem? How much detail does `fanotify` provide?

Comment: Just for your information: Fanotify has a bug. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566755/multi-thread-opening-file-hangs-when-fanotify-is-on here is a patch.
http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=131822913806350&w=2

Answer (score 21):

[This LWN article](http://lwn.net/Articles/339253/) is often quoted as a source of documentation for fanotify. But the description there appears to be out of date. fanotify no longer works using a socket connection. Instead, there are two new libc functions wrapping syscalls, declared in `sys/fanotify.h`. One is called `fanotify_init`, the other is `fanotify_mark`. At the time of this writing, these syscalls are still included in the [list of missing manual pages](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/missing_pages.html). There is, however, a [mail containing drafts](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.man/2375) for these manual pages. With a combination of these man pages, a look at the headers in question, and a bit of trial and error, you should be able to get this going.

It seems that some of the functionality originally envisioned for fanotify is no longer suipported in that fashion. For example, the LWN article describes a `FAN_GLOBAL_LISTENER` flag which will implicitely mark the whole filesystem tree unless parts are explicitely unmarked. The current interface has no such provision, but a similar result can be achieved using the following mark:

```c
fanotify_mark(fan,
              FAN_MARK_ADD | FAN_MARK_MOUNT,
              FAN_OPEN | FAN_EVENT_ON_CHILD,
              AT_FDCWD, "/")
```

Where inotify events provide the path to the accessed object as part of the event, fanotify opens a file descriptor for it. In order to turn this descriptor into a path name, the corresponding entry from the proc file system can be used, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13379632/1468366).

Here is a simple example which simply prints the name of every opened file:

```c
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/fanotify.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#define CHK(expr, errcode) if((expr)==errcode) perror(#expr), exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int fan;
  char buf[4096];
  char fdpath[32];
  char path[PATH_MAX + 1];
  ssize_t buflen, linklen;
  struct fanotify_event_metadata *metadata;
  CHK(fan = fanotify_init(FAN_CLASS_NOTIF, O_RDONLY), -1);
  CHK(fanotify_mark(fan, FAN_MARK_ADD | FAN_MARK_MOUNT,
                    FAN_OPEN | FAN_EVENT_ON_CHILD, AT_FDCWD, "/"), -1);
  for (;;) {
    CHK(buflen = read(fan, buf, sizeof(buf)), -1);
    metadata = (struct fanotify_event_metadata*)&buf;
    while(FAN_EVENT_OK(metadata, buflen)) {
      if (metadata->mask & FAN_Q_OVERFLOW) {
        printf("Queue overflow!\n");
        continue;
      }
      sprintf(fdpath, "/proc/self/fd/%d", metadata->fd);
      CHK(linklen = readlink(fdpath, path, sizeof(path) - 1), -1);
      path[linklen] = '\0';
      printf("%s opened by process %d.\n", path, (int)metadata->pid);
      close(metadata->fd);
      metadata = FAN_EVENT_NEXT(metadata, buflen);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The documentation for the fanotify API is available in the Linux manpages:

- fanotify.7 - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fanotify.7.html
- fanotify_init.2 - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fanotify_init.2.html
- fanotify_mark.2 - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fanotify_mark.2.html

---

Here are some examples, fatrace being the most elaborate.

- https://launchpad.net/fatrace
- http://git.infradead.org/users/eparis/fanotify-example.git
- http://www.lanedo.com/~aleksander/fanotify/fanotify-example.c

Bindings exist for Go and Python.

Answer (score 6):

I just learned about fanotify and it seems very nice. Very nice interface!

It is not in the Linus tree yet but I guess it will get there for Linux 2.6.33 and before for testing (I noticed some patches today in LKML). In the original patch they announce a GIT tree thus you might be able to build a testing kernel from there. You might also find testing git trees.

I couldn't find utilities that use it but I guess they'll come soon.

There is an example here, at the end of the email:

http://lwn.net/Articles/339253/

If you are really interested in this new feature you might want to monitor the Linux Kernel Mailing List and interact there. You can also wait until the utilities are released or develop your own.

About the detail, it seems fanotify provides less events than inotify. I guess this might change in the future but since this is a brand new feature in development there is not much I can say about it now.

Comment: In the end fanotify went into 2.6.36