# multi-thread opening file hangs when fanotify is on

Tags: linux, multithreading, freeze

I use this fanotify sample to monitor open/access perms on the whole file system(/): http://git.infradead.org/users/eparis/fanotify-example.git.

Then I have a test program with multiple threads, each thread iterate the sample foder and open/close the files in it, sometimes my program hangs at open().

OS: Ubuntu 2.6.38-11 x86_64.

Is it a bug of fanotify that it does not support multiple-thread opening?

The code of my test program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <dirent.h>

//open file function    
void open_file( char* file )
{
    int fd = -1;
    fd = open( file, O_WRONLY, 0x666 );
    if( fd >= 0 )
    {
        printf("open:%s\n", file );
        close( fd );
    }
}

//iterate directory function

void printdir(char *dir, int depth)
{
    DIR *dp;
    struct stat statbuf;
    char pathbuf[2048] = {0};
    struct dirent entry;
    struct dirent *entryPtr = NULL;

    //printf("opendir %s\n", dir );
    usleep( 300 );
    if((dp = opendir(dir)) == NULL) {
        if( errno != ENOTDIR )
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"cannot open directory: %s\n", dir);
            perror("open fial");
        }
        return;
    }

    readdir_r( dp, &entry, &entryPtr );
    while( entryPtr != NULL)
    {
        snprintf(pathbuf,2000, "%s/%s\0", dir, entry.d_name );
        printf("iteraotr:%s\n", pathbuf );

        lstat( pathbuf, &statbuf );
        if(S_ISDIR( statbuf.st_mode )) 
        {
            /* Found a directory, but ignore . and .. */
            if(strcmp(".",entry.d_name) == 0 || 
                    strcmp("..",entry.d_name) == 0)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                //printf("%d,%s\n",depth, entry->d_name);
                printdir( pathbuf, depth+1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //printf("%*s%s\n",depth,"",entry->d_name);
            open_file( pathbuf );
        }
        readdir_r( dp, &entry, &entryPtr );
    }
    closedir(dp);
}

//thread function   
void* iterator_dir( void* data )
{
    char* path = (char*)data;
    printf("In iterator_dir(): %s\n", path );

    printdir( path, 0 );

    return NULL;
}


pthread_t  threadID[10] = {0};

 //main function    
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if( argc < 3 )
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <thread_num> <file>\n", argv[0] );
        exit(0);
    }
    if( isdigit( (char)*argv[1] ) == 0 )
    {
        printf(" Thread num is 0 - 9\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    int thread_num = atoi( argv[1] );
    char* res;

    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    int i = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < thread_num; ++i )
    {
        pthread_create( &threadID[i], &attr, &iterator_dir, argv[2]);
    }

    for( i = 0; i < thread_num; ++i )
    {
        pthread_join( threadID[i] , &res );
    }
}
```

**2011-09-28 Edit:**

I comment the open file operation, only keep the iterate directory part. The application still hangs.
This is the output of strace:

```
enter code here
pid 10692] open("/home/byang//.config/menus", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
[pid 10691] write(1, "1213966080 opendir /home/byang//"..., 56) = 56
```

.........

```
[pid 10689] madvise(0x7f3c48dbc000, 8368128, MADV_DONTNEED) = 0
[pid 10689] _exit(0)                    = ?
Process 10689 detached
[pid 10688] <... futex resumed> )       = 0
[pid 10688] futex(0x7f3c47db99d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 10692, NULL <unfinished ...>
```

It hangs here, when I close the fanotify, it continues...

```
[pid 10692] <... open resumed> )        = 11
[pid 10692] getdents(11, /* 4 entries */, 32768) = 128
[pid 10692] lstat("/home/byang//.config/menus/applications.menu", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=233, ...}) = 0
```

10688 is the parent thread; 10689,10691,10692 are the child threads that iterating the directories.
It seems that 10692 are waiting the reply from fanotify?

Comment: Well, 'open()' is called with 3 arguments, but you don't give O_CREAT, so that is wrong - I'd at least fix that, remove the 3. argument. (and 0x666 would anyway not be what you want, but instead 0666). Check all calls for errors as well, to make sure you're not missing anything that fails (e.g. readdir_r,lstat calls). It'd also be interresting to learn what the program is doing when it hangs, so run it through `strace -f`

Comment: I comment the open file, only keep the open directories, problem still exists. I checked the result of readdir_r and lstat, exit when error. The output of strace is updated in body.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug of Kernel's fanotify.
I posted a patch to Linux-Kernel:
When multiple threadsiterate the same direcotry, some thread will hang.
This patch let fanotify differentiate access events from different
threads, prevent fanotify from merging access events from different
threads.

http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=131822913806350&w=2

```
    -------------------------------

    diff -r -u linux-3.1-rc4_orig/fs/notify/fanotify/fanotify.c
    linux-3.1-rc4/fs/notify/fanotify/fanotify.c
    --- linux-3.1-rc4_orig/fs/notify/fanotify/fanotify.c    2011-08-29
    12:16:01.000000000 +0800
    +++ linux-3.1-rc4/fs/notify/fanotify/fanotify.c 2011-10-10
    12:28:23.276847000 +0800
    @@ -15,7 +15,8 @@

            if (old->to_tell == new->to_tell &&
                old->data_type == new->data_type &&
    -           old->tgid == new->tgid) {
    +           old->tgid == new->tgid &&
    +           old->pid == new->pid) {
                    switch (old->data_type) {
                    case (FSNOTIFY_EVENT_PATH):
                            if ((old->path.mnt == new->path.mnt) &&
    @@ -144,11 +145,19 @@
                    return PTR_ERR(notify_event);

     #ifdef CONFIG_FANOTIFY_ACCESS_PERMISSIONS
    -       if (event->mask & FAN_ALL_PERM_EVENTS) {
    -               /* if we merged we need to wait on the new event */
    -               if (notify_event)
    -                       event = notify_event;
    -               ret = fanotify_get_response_from_access(group, event);
    +       //if overflow, do not wait for response
    +       if(fsnotify_isoverflow(event))
    +       {
    +               pr_debug("fanotify overflow!\n");
    +       }
    +       else
    +       {
    +               if (event->mask & FAN_ALL_PERM_EVENTS) {
    +                       /* if we merged we need to wait on the new event */
    +                       if (notify_event)
    +                               event = notify_event;
    +                       ret = fanotify_get_response_from_access(group, event);
    +               }
            }
     #endif

    diff -r -u linux-3.1-rc4_orig/fs/notify/notification.c
    linux-3.1-rc4/fs/notify/notification.c
    --- linux-3.1-rc4_orig/fs/notify/notification.c 2011-08-29
    12:16:01.000000000 +0800
    +++ linux-3.1-rc4/fs/notify/notification.c      2011-10-10 12:27:09.331787000 +0800
    @@ -95,6 +95,7 @@
                    BUG_ON(!list_empty(&event->private_data_list));

                    kfree(event->file_name);
    +               put_pid(event->pid);
                    put_pid(event->tgid);
                    kmem_cache_free(fsnotify_event_cachep, event);
            }
    @@ -132,6 +133,14 @@
            return priv;
     }

    +bool fsnotify_isoverflow(struct fsnotify_event *event)
    +{
    +       if(event==q_overflow_event)
    +       {
    +               return true;
    +       }
    +       return false;
    +}
     /*
      * Add an event to the group notification queue.  The group can later pull this
      * event off the queue to deal with.  If the event is successfully added to the
    @@ -374,6 +383,7 @@
                            return NULL;
                    }
            }
    +       event->pid = get_pid(old_event->pid);
            event->tgid = get_pid(old_event->tgid);
            if (event->data_type == FSNOTIFY_EVENT_PATH)
                    path_get(&event->path);
    @@ -417,6 +427,7 @@
                    event->name_len = strlen(event->file_name);
            }

    +       event->pid = get_pid(task_pid(current));
            event->tgid = get_pid(task_tgid(current));
            event->sync_cookie = cookie;
            event->to_tell = to_tell;
    diff -r -u linux-3.1-rc4_orig/include/linux/fsnotify_backend.h
    linux-3.1-rc4/include/linux/fsnotify_backend.h
    --- linux-3.1-rc4_orig/include/linux/fsnotify_backend.h 2011-08-29
    12:16:01.000000000 +0800
    +++ linux-3.1-rc4/include/linux/fsnotify_backend.h      2011-10-10
    12:27:48.587369000 +0800
    @@ -238,6 +238,7 @@
            u32 sync_cookie;        /* used to corrolate events, namely inotify mv events */
            const unsigned char *file_name;
            size_t name_len;
    +       struct pid *pid;
            struct pid *tgid;

     #ifdef CONFIG_FANOTIFY_ACCESS_PERMISSIONS
    @@ -378,6 +379,8 @@
                                                            struct fsnotify_event_private_data *priv,
                                                            struct fsnotify_event *(*merge)(struct list_head *,
                                                                                            struct fsnotify_event *));
    +/*true if the event is an overflow event*/
    +extern bool fsnotify_isoverflow(struct fsnotify_event *event);
     /* true if the group notification queue is empty */
     extern bool fsnotify_notify_queue_is_empty(struct fsnotify_group *group);
     /* return, but do not dequeue the first event on the notification queue */
```