# How to monitor a complete directory tree for changes in Linux?

Tags: linux, monitoring, filesystemwatcher, inotify

How can I monitor *a whole directory tree* for changes in Linux (*ext3* file system)?

Currently the directory contains about *half a million files* in about **3,000 subdirectories**, organized in three directory levels.

Those are mostly small files (< 1kb, some few up to 100 kb). It's a sort of queue and I need to know when files are being created, deleted or their content modified within 5-10 seconds of that happening.

I know there is *inotify* and sorts, but AFAIK they only monitor a single directory, which means I would need 3,000 inotify handles in my case - more than the usual 1024 handles allowed for a single process. Or am I wrong?

*In case the Linux system can't tell me what I need: perhaps there is a [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) project that simulates a file system (replicating all file accesses on a real file system) and separately logs all modifications (couldn't fine one)?*

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To my knowledge, there's no other way than recursively setting an `inotify` watch on each directory.

That said, you won't run out of file descriptors because `inotify` does not have to reserve an fd to watch a file or a directory (its predecessor, `dnotify`, did suffer from this limitation). `inotify` uses "watch descriptors" instead.

According to the documentation for [inotifywatch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywatch), the default limit is 8192 watch descriptors, and you can increase it by writing the new value to `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`.

Comment: Sounds good. Any negative aspects to consider when using so many watch descriptors?

Comment: Nope, apart from the time taken to create all the watches, I don't think you'll run into issues with only 3000 subdirectories.

Comment: Does this not create possible race issues like: creation of `folder_sub` in `folder_main`, creation `folder_sub_sub` in `folder_sub`, inotify of `folder_main` arrives, watch is set on `folder_sub`, but `folder_sub_sub` is already missed, and thus there is furthermore no watch installed on it?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 now has the default of 'max_user_watches' now set to 65536 which seem to be a reasonable values in normal desktop/server systems.

Comment: @KoenG. yes, that's one possibility of losing some _events_, but you can have "eventual consistency", i.e. you'll know "_1 or more changes happened here_" since your last in-memory picture.  You then install a watch on `main/folder_sub/folder_sub_sub` and read its current files.  By that time, it's possible that some file was created, changed and deleted and you'll not even know it.  
Consider inotify as optimized "trigger to re-scan", not "full history"; if you must have full history go for something like FUSE or strace.

Answer (score 104):

I've done something similar using the `inotifywait` tool:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do

inotifywait -e modify,create,delete -r /path/to/your/dir && \
<some command to execute when a file event is recorded>

done
```

This will setup recursive directory watches on the entire tree and allow you to execute a command when something changes. If you just want to view the changes, you can add the `-m` flag to put it into monitor mode.

Comment: To avoid the `while loop`use the `-m` or `--monitor` switch/option/flag/arg. Don't know when that 'switch' came into being, but is better than loops

Comment: You should also add the `move` event:

`inotifywait -e modify,create,delete,move -r /path/to/your/dir`

Comment: Couldn't this approach miss an event in case when two of them happen in a split second? After inotifywait exists there would be a period when no events are monitored, wouldn't it?

Comment: @gwillie, but if `m` flag is used, it just outputs to `stdout` and we cannot execute any command using that trigger. So, if you want to execute something after any event is observed, isn't the `while` loop better?

Comment: `inotifywait -e modify -m | while read line; do something_with $line; done`

Answer (score 52):

```
$ inotifywait -m -r /path/to/your/directory
```

This command is enough to watch the directory recursively for all events such as access, open, create, delete ...

Comment: Yes but events such as access and open are very problematic. Depending of what your intent is. Example: I wanted to relaunch `cordova run` each time something change in www directory. As result, the open,access events generated by cordova was triggering inotifywait, entering in an infinite loop. `-e modify,create,delete,move` is better for most uses.

Answer (score 23):

inotify is the best option when you have many subdirectories but if not I am used to using this command below:

`watch -d find <<path>>`

Comment: watch is def preferred

Comment: `watch` doesn't allow paging, so it'll lose anything that is longer than the terminal height (e.g., `tree` commands with number of files > terminal row count)

Comment: I'd love to see the hardware (and what that method does to its workload) that supports a `find` on half a million files every 5-10 seconds. ... if I were your sysadmin and saw you creating this kind of load I'd hunt you down and give you a **very** stern talking to.

Comment: @tink Definitely, if you have a lot of files to inspect, run `find` many times is not the way to go. My answer helps folks who want to inspect the subdirectories and don't have access to `inotify`. As I suggested `inotify` is the best one when you have a lot of files.

Answer (score 13):

Use inotifywait from inotify-tools:

`sudo apt install inotify-tools`

Now create a script `myscript.sh` that includes hidden files and folders too:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do

inotifywait -e modify,create,delete,move -r $1

done
```

Make the script executable with `chmod +x myscript.sh`

Run it with `./myscript.sh /folder/to/monitor`

If you don't provide argument it will use the working directory by default.

Also, you can run several commands adding `&& \` at the end of the previous command to add the next one:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do

inotifywait -e modify,create,delete,move -r $1 && \
echo "event" && \
echo "event 2"

done
```

If you don't want to execute any command on events, just run the command directly with the `-m` modifier so doesn't close:

`inotifywait -e modify,create,delete,move -m -r /path/to/your/dir`

Answer (score 9):

I have a different suggestion, only for changes in the files, and record history changes

use git

```sh
cd /folder_to_monitor
git init
git add *
git commit -m "first snapshot"
```

so after you make the changes

```sh
git diff
```

Comment: it may be a valid option in some situations. Doesn't deserve a -1

Answer (score 4):

Wasn't fanotify supposed to provide that capability eventually?
Quoting [LWN](https://lwn.net/Articles/339253/):

“*fanotify has two basic 'modes' directed and global. [...] fanotify global instead indicates
that it wants everything on the system and then individually marks
inodes that it doesn't care about.*”

I lost track what its latest status was, though.

Comment: According to a comment against http://stackoverflow.com/a/1847268/130352 ... fanotify went into 2.6.36.

Answer (score 2):

Especially for large or complex monitoring tasks in which you want to trigger events based on what you see, check out [Watchman A file watching service](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/). Here is a simple example to run a tool named minify-css whenever a CSS file is changed:

```
$ watchman watch ~/src
$ watchman -- trigger ~/src buildme '*.css' -- minify-css
```

It does comprehensive logging, can efficiently handle multiple watches that overlap in a directory structure, can be administered from the command line or via json, and much more. See also

- [Watchman – A File and Directory Watching Tool for Changes](https://www.tecmint.com/watchman-monitor-file-changes-in-linux/)

It is available via Debian Sid and Ubuntu 20.04, and has nearly made it in to Fedora twice from what I can see ([1450590](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1450590) and [1564720](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1564720)).

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem, having a program that was creating some files (starting with a dot) whose content I wanted to manually inspect, but it automatically deleted them again soon after creation.

Using inotify in a loop without the monitor option didn't work for me, because it was too slow and missed events, so I came up with this script:

```
target="$1"

cd "$target"
mkdir backup/

inotifywait -e modify,create,delete --monitor -r --include "\..*" "$target" | \
while read line
do
  echo "$line"
  if [[ "$line" == "$target CREATE "* ]] || [[ "$line" == "$target MODIFY "* ]]
  then
    filename=${line#"$target CREATE "}
    filename=${filename#"$target MODIFY "}
    cp --verbose "$filename" backup/
  fi
done
```

Answer (score -1):

use watch command, its easy to use and a native Linux command (installed on almost every linux distro)

```
watch -n <interval> <command> <path>
```

e.g.

this will show /tmp/test directory changes for every 200 milliseconds

```
watch -n 0.2 ls -la /tmp/test
```

for recursive usage you can use **watch** like below

```
 watch -n 0.2 find <path>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It runs the command if I `touch /tmp/test/x` but it doesn't if I `touch /tmp/test/subdir/y`. The question is explicitly looking for a recursive solution.

Comment: yes, you're right, we could achieve that functionality with using `watch` command with `find`

Comment: Now  you're just repeating answers from [half a decade ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50728356/19068).

Answer (score -3):

I use this to get a quick overview in the current directory:

```
watch 'find . -printf "%T@ %Tc %p\n" | sort -nr | head '
```

Comment: Downvoted because 1) it does not answer the question (`head` would trim the vast majority of the output) and 2) given the number of files and directories of the OP this answer would be impractical even if it were correct because it would periodically look at all the files over again. The OP was looking for a more robust and low-overhead solution.