# How to tell which path a fanotify event refers to

Tags: linux, fanotify

I'd like to find out which files are opened on my system in which order, in order to prefetch them from disk. It seems that [fanotify](http://lwn.net/Articles/339253/) should be well suited to monitor the whole system for open events. But as far as I can tell, the `fanotify_event_metadata` structure does not have a field to contain the path. So how can I tell which path a given event refers to? Or is fanotify the wrong approach to find path names, and do I have to recursively register watches for the whole tree using inotify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `readlink` on `/proc/self/fd/<fdnum>`, where `fdnum` refers to the `fd` member of the `struct fanotify_event_metadata` for the event.

Comment: My ```fd``` is always ```-1```